# bloodhound installation stuck , no such file or directory

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, apache-bloodhound

I am on centos 6 64bit. following the basic bloodhound guide https://issues.apache.org/bloodhound/wiki/BloodhoundInstall i am getting the following error..

```
(bloodhound)[root@cobra apache-bloodhound-0.7]# cd installer/
(bloodhound)[root@cobra installer]# pip install -r requirements.txt
Unpacking /opt/html/apache-bloodhound-0.7/trac
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///opt/html/apache-bloodhound-0.7/trac
Unpacking /opt/html/apache-bloodhound-0.7/bloodhound_multiproduct
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///opt/html/apache-bloodhound-0.7/bloodhound_multiproduct
Unpacking /opt/html/apache-bloodhound-0.7/bloodhound_dashboard
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///opt/html/apache-bloodhound-0.7/bloodhound_dashboard
    warning: no files found matching 'LICENSE'
    warning: no files found matching 'NOTICE'
    warning: no directories found matching 'bhdashboard/widgets/htdocs'
Unpacking /opt/html/apache-bloodhound-0.7/bloodhound_theme
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///opt/html/apache-bloodhound-0.7/bloodhound_theme
    warning: no directories found matching 'bhtheme/htdocs/images'
Unpacking /opt/html/apache-bloodhound-0.7/bloodhound_search
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///opt/html/apache-bloodhound-0.7/bloodhound_search
Unpacking /opt/html/apache-bloodhound-0.7/bloodhound_relations
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///opt/html/apache-bloodhound-0.7/bloodhound_relations
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Pygments in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 18))
Downloading/unpacking pytz==2013b (from -r requirements.txt (line 19))
  Downloading pytz-2013b.tar.bz2 (199kB): 199kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pytz
    warning: no files found matching '*.pot' under directory 'pytz'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'test_zdump.py'
Downloading/unpacking sqlparse==0.1.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
  Downloading sqlparse-0.1.7.tar.gz (50kB): 50kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package sqlparse
Downloading/unpacking Babel==0.9.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 21))
  Downloading Babel-0.9.6.tar.gz (1.8MB): 1.8MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package Babel
Downloading/unpacking Genshi==0.6.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 22))
  Downloading Genshi-0.6.1.tar.gz (486kB): 486kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package Genshi
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'doc/logo.lineform'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'doc/2000ft.graffle'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
Downloading/unpacking TracAccountManager (from -r requirements.txt (line 24))
  Downloading TracAccountManager-0.4.4.tar.gz (157kB): 157kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package TracAccountManager
Downloading/unpacking TracThemeEngine (from -r requirements.txt (line 26))
  You are installing an externally hosted file. Future versions of pip will default to disallowing externally hosted files.
  Downloading TracThemeEngine-2.2.1.zip (200kB): 200kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package TracThemeEngine
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.swp' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.swo' found anywhere in distribution
Downloading/unpacking TracPermRedirect (from -r requirements.txt (line 29))
  Downloading TracPermRedirect-3.0.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package TracPermRedirect
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools>=0.6b1 in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from Trac==1.0.1->-r requirements.txt (line 23))
Downloading/unpacking whoosh==2.4.1 (from BloodhoundSearchPlugin==0.7.0->-r requirements.txt (line 30))
  Downloading Whoosh-2.4.1.tar.gz (938kB): 938kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package whoosh
    warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'benchmark'
    warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'files'
    warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'files'
    warning: no files found matching '*.jpg' under directory 'files'
Installing collected packages: pytz, sqlparse, Babel, Genshi, TracAccountManager, TracThemeEngine, TracPermRedirect, BloodhoundMultiProduct, BloodhoundDashboardPlugin, BloodhoundTheme, whoosh, BloodhoundSearchPlugin, BloodhoundRelationsPlugin
  Running setup.py install for pytz
    warning: no files found matching '*.pot' under directory 'pytz'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'test_zdump.py'
  Running setup.py install for sqlparse
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.6/sqlformat from 644 to 755
    changing mode of /opt/html/apache-bloodhound-0.7/bloodhound/bin/sqlformat to 755
  Found existing installation: Babel 0.9.4
    Not uninstalling Babel at /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages, outside environment /opt/html/apache-bloodhound-0.7/bloodhound
  Running setup.py install for Babel
    Installing pybabel script to /opt/html/apache-bloodhound-0.7/bloodhound/bin
  Found existing installation: Genshi 0.7
    Not uninstalling Genshi at /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Genshi-0.7-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg, outside environment /opt/html/apache-bloodhound-0.7/bloodhound
  Running setup.py install for Genshi
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'doc/logo.lineform'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'doc/2000ft.graffle'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  Running setup.py install for TracAccountManager
    compiling catalog 'acct_mgr/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.po' to 'acct_mgr/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.mo'
    compiling catalog 'acct_mgr/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.po' to 'acct_mgr/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.mo'
    compiling catalog 'acct_mgr/locale/id_ID/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.po' to 'acct_mgr/locale/id_ID/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.mo'
    compiling catalog 'acct_mgr/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.po' to 'acct_mgr/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.mo'
    compiling catalog 'acct_mgr/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.po' to 'acct_mgr/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.mo'
    compiling catalog 'acct_mgr/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.po' to 'acct_mgr/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.mo'
    compiling catalog 'acct_mgr/locale/et/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.po' to 'acct_mgr/locale/et/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.mo'
    compiling catalog 'acct_mgr/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.po' to 'acct_mgr/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.mo'
    compiling catalog 'acct_mgr/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.po' to 'acct_mgr/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.mo'
    compiling catalog 'acct_mgr/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.po' to 'acct_mgr/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.mo'
    compiling catalog 'acct_mgr/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.po' to 'acct_mgr/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.mo'
    compiling catalog 'acct_mgr/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.po' to 'acct_mgr/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.mo'
    compiling catalog 'acct_mgr/locale/te/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.po' to 'acct_mgr/locale/te/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.mo'
    compiling catalog 'acct_mgr/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.po' to 'acct_mgr/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.mo'
    compiling catalog 'acct_mgr/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.po' to 'acct_mgr/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.mo'
    compiling catalog 'acct_mgr/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.po' to 'acct_mgr/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.mo'
    compiling catalog 'acct_mgr/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.po' to 'acct_mgr/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.mo'
    compiling catalog 'acct_mgr/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.po' to 'acct_mgr/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.mo'
    compiling catalog 'acct_mgr/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.po' to 'acct_mgr/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.mo'
    compiling catalog 'acct_mgr/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.po' to 'acct_mgr/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/acct_mgr.mo'
  Running setup.py install for TracThemeEngine
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.swp' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.swo' found anywhere in distribution
  Running setup.py install for TracPermRedirect
  Running setup.py install for BloodhoundMultiProduct
  Running setup.py install for BloodhoundDashboardPlugin
    warning: no files found matching 'LICENSE'
    warning: no files found matching 'NOTICE'
    warning: no directories found matching 'bhdashboard/widgets/htdocs'
  Running setup.py install for BloodhoundTheme
    warning: no directories found matching 'bhtheme/htdocs/images'
  Running setup.py install for whoosh
    warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'benchmark'
    warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'files'
    warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'files'
    warning: no files found matching '*.jpg' under directory 'files'
  Running setup.py install for BloodhoundSearchPlugin
  Running setup.py install for BloodhoundRelationsPlugin
Successfully installed pytz sqlparse Babel Genshi TracAccountManager TracThemeEngine TracPermRedirect BloodhoundMultiProduct BloodhoundDashboardPlugin BloodhoundTheme whoosh BloodhoundSearchPlugin BloodhoundRelationsPlugin
Cleaning up...
(bloodhound)[root@cobra installer]# python bloodhound_setup.py 

This installer is able to install Apache Bloodhound with either SQLite or
PostgreSQL databases. SQLite is an easier option for installing Bloodhound as
SQLite is usually built into Python and also requires no special permissions to
run. However, PostgreSQL is generally expected to be more robust for production
use.
Do you want to install to a PostgreSQL database [Y/n]: n

Please supply a username for the admin user [admin]: 
Enter a new password for "admin": 
Please reenter the password: 
Initenv for '/opt/html/apache-bloodhound-0.7/installer/bloodhound/environments/main' failed. 
Wrong number of arguments: 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bloodhound_setup.py", line 458, in <module>
    bsetup.setup()
  File "bloodhound_setup.py", line 244, in setup
    self.writeconfig(baseini, [base_config, accounts_config])
  File "bloodhound_setup.py", line 313, in writeconfig
    config.save()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Trac-1.0.1-py2.6.egg/trac/config.py", line 237, in save
    with AtomicFile(self.filename, 'w') as fileobj:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Trac-1.0.1-py2.6.egg/trac/util/__init__.py", line 171, in __init__
    (fd, self._temp) = tempfile.mkstemp(prefix=name + '-', dir=dir)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/tempfile.py", line 293, in mkstemp
    return _mkstemp_inner(dir, prefix, suffix, flags)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/tempfile.py", line 228, in _mkstemp_inner
    fd = _os.open(file, flags, 0600)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/html/apache-bloodhound-0.7/installer/bloodhound/environments/main/conf/base.ini-0mzAju'
```

see site packages below. i have 2 versions of pip and virtualenv. shall i remove it so there is only 1 version?

```
ll /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
total 736
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Aug 19 12:25 AdvancedTicketWorkflowPlugin-0.11dev_r13338-py2.6.egg
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Jun 20 17:33 babel
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jun 20 17:33 Babel-0.9.4-py2.6.egg-info
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jun 20 17:33 distribute-0.6.10-py2.6.egg-info
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   502 Aug 20 11:20 easy-install.pth
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   126 Nov 12  2010 easy_install.py
-rw-r--r--  2 root root   317 Nov 12  2010 easy_install.pyc
-rw-r--r--  2 root root   317 Nov 12  2010 easy_install.pyo
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Jun 20 17:37 Genshi-0.7-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  4096 Jun 10 15:35 iniparse
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  1085 Aug 17  2010 iniparse-0.3.1-py2.6.egg-info
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  4330 Aug 14  2009 libproxy.py
-rw-r--r--  2 root root  3990 Feb 20  2013 libproxy.pyc
-rw-r--r--  2 root root  3990 Feb 20  2013 libproxy.pyo
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4096 Aug 20 12:19 pip
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Aug 20 12:19 pip-1.3.1-py2.6.egg-info
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 88196 Nov 12  2010 pkg_resources.py
-rw-r--r--  2 root root 92875 Nov 12  2010 pkg_resources.pyc
-rw-r--r--  2 root root 92875 Nov 12  2010 pkg_resources.pyo
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root  4096 Jun 20 17:33 pygments
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jun 20 17:33 Pygments-1.1.1-py2.6.egg-info
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  4096 Jun 10 15:45 rpmUtils
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Jun 20 17:33 setuptools
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   144 Nov 12  2010 setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    33 Aug 19 16:44 setuptools.pth
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2362 Nov 12  2010 site.py
-rw-r--r--  2 root root  1771 Nov 12  2010 site.pyc
-rw-r--r--  2 root root  1771 Nov 12  2010 site.pyo
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4096 Jun 20 17:37 Trac-1.0.1-py2.6.egg
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Aug 19 12:23 TracAnnouncer-1.0dev_r13984-py2.6.egg
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Aug 20 11:18 Tracbacks-0.2dev_r12197-py2.6.egg
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Aug 19 11:39 TracDragDrop-0.12.0.12_r13613-py2.6.egg
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Aug 20 11:20 TracDuplicates-0.11-py2.6.egg
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Aug 20 11:05 TracTicketChangelogPlugin-0.2dev_r13960-py2.6.egg
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  4096 Jun 10 15:45 urlgrabber
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  2285 Jul 30  2013 urlgrabber-3.9.1-py2.6.egg-info
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 54516 Aug 15  2013 virtualenv-1.10.1-py2.6.egg-info
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Aug 20 12:19 virtualenv-1.11.6-py2.6.egg-info
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 97379 Aug 15  2013 virtualenv.py
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 82291 Aug 15  2013 virtualenv.pyc
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 81691 Aug 15  2013 virtualenv.pyo
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Aug 20 12:21 virtualenv_support
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  4096 Jun 10 15:45 yum
```

Comment: it looks like you did not activate your virtualenv before running bloodhound_setup.

Comment: The virtualenv appears to be activated. There is a `(bloodhound)` at the front of the shell prompt. The issue reported here has been seen [previously](http://markmail.org/thread/era5tkxzg6uh2rqa), but I'm not sure of the cause and haven't been able to reproduce.

Comment: I have found resolution the, online documentation is not as clear as the one found in the zip package of 0.7. you have to `cd installer`