# installing apache bloodhound error

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu-14.04, apache-bloodhound

I am installing Apache Bloodhound in Ubuntu 14.04 following the link:
https://issues.apache.org/bloodhound/wiki/BloodhoundDetailedInstallation

However, But when I went to there: 
pip install -r requirements.txt
It had some problems like that:
    warning: no files found matching 'LICENSE'
    warning: no files found matching 'NOTICE'
    warning: no directories found matching 'bhdashboard/widgets/htdocs'
I searched and I found unclear answer (for me):
http://t211424.apache-bloodhound-development.apachetalks.us/problem-running-test-on-bloodhound-dashboard-t211424.html

I would like to ask you about the solution for that. Thanks so much.

Comment: Do you have the same problem as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25403662/33499), looks like there was a `cd installer` missing in the instructions.

Comment: The warning may be entirely harmless. I recall some warnings in the install process. Are you having a problem with the install?

Comment: Thanks so much. Actually, they are harmless. It is my mistake for another process.